# Почему QTableView не отображает записи модели QSqlTableModel?

Tags: sqlite, qtcreator, qt, c++

Пытаюсь отобразить таблицу из бызы данных на виджете QTableView

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("sqltemp.db");
db.open();
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(0, db);
model->setTable("spravki");
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
db.close();
```

но в итоге отображаются только заголовки полей (столбцов). Как отобразить и строки (record) тоже?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить между

```
model->setTable("spravki");
```

и

```
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

вызов метода `select()` таким образом:

```
model->select();
```

За подробностями Вы можете обратиться к [документации](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqltablemodel.html#select)